# If $a^n$ is a unit then $a$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $\alpha \in R$. Show that if $a^n$ is a unit then $a$ is unit.

My attempt:
If $a^n$ is a unit, then $\exists u \in R$ such that $a^n \cdot u = 1$ and $ u\cdot a^n = 1$. Thus we have $a\cdot(a^{n-1}\cdot u) = 1$ and $(u  \cdot a^{n-1}) \cdot a = 1$. It remains to show that $ (u  \cdot a^{n-1}) = (a^{n-1}\cdot u)$. Any ideas on how to go about showing this?

Comment: You need that n > 0. And more generally, any divisor of a unit is again a unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very standard fact that if an element $x$ has both a left and a right inverse, then they must be equal, and so $x$ is invertible. Indeed, assume $xy=zx=1$. Then:

$z=z(xy)=(zx)y=y$